# Building User ID/Password Functionality with Ruby on Rails? Overkill?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, userid

I am new to this community, but I am working on a site that requires implementation of a user/password/register check upon entry, which would check against a database, or write to the database, in the case of registration. I have experience with XHTML and CSS, and just discovered RoR. I honestly have very little insight into how to achieve my goal using just XHTML, so I decided to learn Ruby, taking a shot in the dark. I'm wondering if there's an easier language, or more direct fix that I should be implementing instead. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking at [Restful Authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master).

Also, for good code examples in general, have a look at [Altered Beast](http://github.com/technoweenie/altered_beast/tree). It's a forum built in Ruby on Rails and it uses Restful Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for information on how to implement user authentication in Rails? You could try [`acts_as_authenticated`](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/Acts_as_authenticated).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the book called [Agile Web Development with rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition).  It has two parts, a step-by-step walkthrough of creating an application, and a reference section on rails.  I recently started a contract job where I chose RoR as my framework without any experience in it.  This book has been an immense resource to teach me Ruby on Rails.  It also specifically teaches how to implement the authorization you are talking about.